# Is there a way to get *only* related object's PKs from M2M relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

consider the below:

```
class Tag(Model):
    ...

class Post(Model):
    tags = ManyToManyField(Tag) # a join table "post_tags" is created

post = Post.objects.get(pk=1)
post.tags.all()  # this will cause django to join "tag" with "post_tags"
post.tags.values('pk') # even though pk is already in post_tags, django will still join with "tag" table
```

My need is only the list of PKs. Does anyone know of a supported way, or a clean hack where I can just get the PKs from an M2M without an additional join to the actual related table?

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout django doc about [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). Quoting the docs:

> prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each
>   relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to
>   prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done
>   using select_related, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one
>   relationships that are supported by select_related.

So it should be:

```
post = Post.objects.filter(pk=1).prefetch_related('tags')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define relation using [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) argument:

```
class Tag(Model):
    pass


class Post(Model):
    tags = ManyToManyField(Tag, through='PostTag') 


class PostTag(Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

then

```
PostTag.objects.filter(post_id=1).values('tag_id')
```

will perform in a single query, like this:

```
SELECT `appname_posttag`.`tag_id` FROM `appname_posttag` WHERE `appname_posttag`.`post_id` = 1
```